# How to retrieve Id from URL (query params) in Next.js 13 client component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a problem, I'm using Next.js 13 but I cannot use it in the client component useRouter from next/router how can I retrieve in my case eventId from URL?

I'm redirecting from the PaidsCard component where I'm fetching images to [event details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AYMn.png) page, and when I'm clicking some images I want to shift to the event details page where I want to fetch the same image as I have in the PaidCards component

I want to retrieve eventId value from URL and pass in to event details page to fetch data with the exact eventId
my URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/event?eventId=b8050f0e-ef20-40252-9f7f-c883Ffab558f.webp
```

I did try use router from next/router
I did try use  router from next/navigation and here query is not working on router.
I did try useSearchParams and usePathName

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to make it appropriate for Stackoverflow, or it may be closed. Do not post code in images, post the code itself. Remove demands such as "expecting to resolve asap". And please edit your question to be clear, your sentences are jumbled, and you have statements like "not working," we don't know what that means, please be as specific as possible about what you're expecting to happen, and what you're seeing instead.

Comment: @AndyRay thank you for your reply, you are correct. my question is not well structured and also I agree with ASAP. sorry, I just registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> useSearchParams is a Client Component hook that lets you read the current URL's query string.

example from [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params):

```js
'use client'
 
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function SearchBar() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
 
  const search = searchParams.get('search')
 
  // URL -> `/dashboard?search=my-project`
  // `search` -> 'my-project'
  return <>Search: {search}</>
}
```

so in you example :

```js
const eventId = searchParams.get('eventId')
```

Answer (score 1):

See if you are able to get the query params using `useRouter` package.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
```

and in the component,

```
const router = useRouter();
const {eventId} = router.query;
```

Comment: unfortunately, when I'm trying to import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

I got an error (Next router was not mounted)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a mistake of next.js,
you can import 'useRouter' which not from 'next/router',try import it from 'next/navigation',and
'const router = useRouter();
use 'router.push(`{url}`);'
'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).